# Let $S$ be a vector space. I want to show that for every subspace $U$ of $S$, the closure $\bar U$ is again a subspace of $S$.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose $S$ is a vector space with norm $|| \ ||$ and $\rho$ the corresponding metric.

I want to show that for every subspace $U$ of $S$, the closure $\bar U$ is again a subspace of $S$.

I've proven several results:

> $U$ is dense in $S$ if and only if $\bar U = S$
>
> $x \in \bar U \iff \forall \epsilon > 0: b_{\rho}(x,\epsilon) \cap U \neq \emptyset$
>
> $x \in \bar U$ if and only if there exist a sequence $(x_n)$ in $U$ such that $\rho(x_n,x) \rightarrow 0$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$

However, I don't see how to apply this in proving the question.

Comment: Here are some hints. You won't need your first observation. The other two can be useful. You have to show that $\bar U$ is closed under the vector space operations, namely addition and scalar multiplication. Take, for example, addition. Pick $x,y \in \bar U$. Then you have to show that $x+y \in \bar U$. To this end, pick sequences $x_n, y_n \in U$ with $x_n \rightarrow x$ and $y_n \rightarrow y$. Now, prove that $x_n + y_n \rightarrow x+y$. Scalar multiplication is similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One has to show that $\bar{U}$ is closed w.r.t. linear combinations. If $x,y\in\bar{U}$, there are sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ in $U$ such that $x_n\rightarrow x$ and $y_n\rightarrow y$ for $n\rightarrow\infty$. If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are scalars, then
$$
\rho(\alpha x_n+\beta y_n,\alpha x+ \beta y)
=\|\alpha x_n+\beta y_n-\alpha x-\beta y\|\leq|\alpha|\underbrace{\|x_n-x\|}_{\rightarrow\;0}+|\beta|\underbrace{\|y_n-y\|}_{\rightarrow\;0}\rightarrow 0
$$
and hence $\alpha x+ \beta y\in\bar{U}$.

Comment: Thanks. I see how I should use what I've already proved myself. The missing link was that I'd forgot how the corresponding metric of the norm was defined.